# Integrating a VIN Decoder API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I have never integrated an API into any of my app's before. I want to integrate a basic VIN decoder API, that will provide basic vehicle information after a vehicle's VIN is submitted. I want to use the NHTSA Vehicle API as it is free and simple. I am most familiar with Javascript and they provide a code example which I will provide below. How do I integrate this API into my simple HTML form? Thanks for your help!

Link to VIN Decoder: [NHTSA VIN Decoder API](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/Home/Index/LanguageExamples)

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input {width: 200px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="VIN - 17 Digits" name="name" maxlength="100">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="15" cols="100" placeholder="Vehicle Data Presented Here"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

"Javascript with jQuery, Get Example":

```js
$.ajax({
 url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeId/440?format=json",
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(result)
 {
  console.log(result);
 },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
 {
  console.log(xhr.status);
  console.log(thrownError);
 }
});
```

"Javascript with jQuery, Post Example":

```js
$.ajax({
 url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/",
 type: "POST",
 data: { format: "json", data: "3GNDA13D76S000000;5XYKT3A12CG000000;"},
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(result)
 {
  console.log(result);
 },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
 {
  console.log(xhr.status);
  console.log(thrownError);
 }
});
```

Comment: you have to on form submit, take the value from the form input and put it in the Data part of the "Post" example. The example includes two VIN numbers, but you'd only need the one. Make sure to still append a semicolon to the VIN input.

Comment: The GET example is the wrong example, you're not getting make and model information for a list of cars, but asking for info about a specific VIN.

Comment: @mix3d Can you expand on that?

Comment: Was trying to lead to discovering the answer rather than solve it outright.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="Enter VINs-separated by ;" name="b12" maxlength="100"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="100" id="results" placeholder="Vehicle Data Presented Here"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
  var val = $("#b12").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { format: "json", data: val},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#results").val(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
})
```

I'll leave it up to you to parse the results into what you want to present...

Answer (score 1):

A few different things here. You should read up on how to use APIs using jQuery. Here's a quick but effective example I found elsewhere:

https://www.yogihosting.com/example-jquery-ajax-call-api/

First, set up your HTML to be easy to interact with JavaScript by adding an `id` to your `button` and your `textarea` elements:

`<button id="btn_submit">Submit</button>`

`<textarea id="txt_results" rows="15" cols="100" placeholder="Vehicle Data Presented Here"></textarea>`

Next, add an event listener for when the Submit button is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("btn_submit").onclick = function () {
  var vin;

  vin = document.getElementById("b12").value;

  if (vin.length === 17) {
    getNHTSADataByVIN(vin);
  }
};
```

Now the fun part. In jQuery's AJAX calls, you get to decide what happens with the data you recieve from the call in the `success` parameter. In the API's example usage, you are able to do whatever you want with the `result` parameter once it is returned. Here is a function that will pass the `result` object into a function that will display the results (that we are about to write):

```
function getNHTSADataByVIN (param_vin) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { format: "json", data: param_vin },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result)
    {
      console.log(result);
      displayNHTSAResults(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
  });
};
```

Finally, we create a function that takes the properties inside of the result objects and writes them out to the text area if the property isn't empty:

```
function displayNHTSAResults (param_data) {
  var output_text = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < param_data.Results.length; i++) {
    var result = param_data.Results[i];

    for (var prop in result) {
      if (result.hasOwnProperty(prop) && result[prop] !== "") {
        output_text += prop + ": " + result[prop] + "\n";
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("txt_results").value = output_text;
};
```

Of course, there are many ways to do this, but hopefully this serves as a good simple demonstration of API usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function CheckVin(vin) {
    var response = await fetch(`https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevin/${vin}?format=json`);
    let result = await response.json();
    result = result.Results.reduce((accumulator, crr) => {
        if (crr.Value && crr.Value != 'Not Applicable') {
            accumulator[crr.VariableId] = {
                variable: crr.Variable,
                value: crr.Value
            }
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, {})
    
    if(result['143'].value !== '0'){
        throw result['191'].value;
    }

    return result;
}
```